# Eclipse CDT: force indexing conditionally compiled code

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Our code base conditionally compiles code based on compile-time configs. CDT plugin in Eclipse currently does not index compiled-out code, so I can't jump to a function definition if it's within `#ifdef`. How could I enable indexing to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assume that code would compile if the conditionals are ignored. In this light this feature cannot work (in the general case).

I suggest using a build configuration that defines all the required symbols to compile all the blocks. Of course that means that instead of having

```
#ifdef FEATURE_X
    code;
#else
    other code;
#endif
```

you'll have to use the more cumbersome

```
#ifdef FEATURE_X
    code;
#endif
#ifdef FEATURE_Y
    other code;
#endif
```

So you can let the indexer work with `-DFEATURE_X -DFEATURE_Y`. However, you can't debug in such configuration, because both blocks would get executed as well